# How to replace the page url for the page slug in a menu link?

Tags: menus

I am developing a single page site within WordPress, that contains multiple sections. These sections are pages in WordPress.

In my `index.php` I loop through all pages within WordPress and add them to the index file - front page with a custom loop.

*Loop through all pages*

```
<?php 
    $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
    $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
?>
<?php if ($loop) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <?php $slides = get_field('flexslider'); ?>
    <?php 
        if ($slides) { 
            get_template_part( 'templates/slideshow' );
        } else {
            get_template_part( 'templates/parallax' );
        } 
    ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**MENU**

Because I developing a single page layout, I should modify the basic WordPress navigation to output the right menu links specific for this type of layout. So the normal output (I removed the `id` and `class` attributes to focus on the right thing) should be replaced for a hashtag and the slug of the page.

*Basic menu link markup:*

```
<li id="" class=""><a href="http://prachtelectronica.nl/wordpress/?page_id=10" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Lightning</a></li>
```

*Modified menu link (what I wish):*

```
<li id="" class=""><a href="#lightning" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Lightning</a></li>
```

I use the following WordPress function to build a menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
       'menu' => 'primary-menu',
       'container' => 'nav',
       'container_id' => 'primary-navwrapper',
       'menu_id' => 'listnav',
    ));
?>
```

I would like that the position of each section (page) will be determine by the menu order that is set in `Appearance > Menu`, so the customer has only three thing to do when creating a new section (page). (1) Create a page, (2) add the page to the menu (3) and order it inside the menu structure.

I already using the `menu_order` property inside my page loop (as you can see above) to display the pages inside the `index.php` file. The order of the menu is used to position the sections (pages) in the right order.

One extra option for the pages is that the user can add a custom template to a page by selecting the template `ads` inside the WP editor. Pages that make use of this template named, "ads", should be displayed in index.php as a section, but not appears as a menu item in the list of menu item, because these sections are not relevant for the primary content.

I hope there is a solution for my wish. If you have any questions, please let me know it in the comments below. 
For now, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query does not fetch the pages added to the menu, but all pages published. And the ordering is not the order in which they have been ordered in the menu (this is independent of menu_order, which is used for wp_page_menu(), admin pages and queries ordered by menu_order). To get the pages in a specific menu and in its order check the function [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to change the Link, you can hook into the `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_209457_nav_menu_link_attributes' ) ) {
    function wpse_209457_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts, $item, $args ) {
        if ( 'primary-menu' == $args->theme_location ) {
            // Get the target posts slug
            $object_data = get_post( $item->object_id );
            $atts['href'] = '#'.$object_data->post_name;
            return $atts;
        }
    }
}
 add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse_209457_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 3 );
```

To make specific items not appear in menus depending on the template they use would be better suited in a separate question, but I'm going to post the solution anyway. You need to use another hook here:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_209457_wp_nav_menu_objects' ) ) {
    function wpse_209457_wp_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
        foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $item ) {
            $template = get_post_meta( $item->object_id, '_wp_page_template', true );
            if ( "templates/ads.php" == $template ) {
                unset( $sorted_menu_items[$key] );
            }
        }
        return $sorted_menu_items;
    }
}
add_filter ( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpse_209457_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2 );
```

I didn't run this code, I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you JHoffmann, is this also possible with wp_page_menu? Because I also need this for `wp_page_menu `. If you have also an code for that, it would be absolute great. I am very greatful!

Comment: I guess this is not possible, as the filter is called in [Walker_Nav_Menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/) class and as far as I know wp_page_menu does not work with Walkers.

Comment: Hmm, I ask this because I am stuck with the following: I create a single page site. In index.php I loop through all pages within WordPress and add them to the index file - front page with a custom loop. What I want is that the menu order determine on which position each section (page) should be placed. I use the `menu_order` to order the sections. But there are some sections that are using a custom template. These sections should not appear in the menu as a link, only as the page. And the links should be replaced with #slug. Do you have any ideas how to achieve this. It would help me so much.

Comment: Please extend your question to include this information. And please make it clear what you mean by "These sections should not appear in the menu as a link, only as the page."
I guess I have the solution you need, I will extend my answer when your question states clearer, what you need.

Comment: My apologize for that it is not entirely clear, I've updated my question. Sounds at least promising. Would be very nice if you have an answer to this question!

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. I will go test it out and let you know if it is working correct!

Comment: I have added the ad page to the menu via Appearance > Menus. And select the ads template in the page editor. Still the adv will appears in the menu. Adv template: http://snippi.com/s/xybpeew Saved in the folder `templates/ads.php`. Menu function that I used is the same as I mentioned in my question above. To change the URL to #slug is working great! Hope the new code we also get to work!

Comment: I had forgotten to specify which meta to load. See the line: `$template = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );`

Comment: Almost there. You're thought is clear, but it will still not exclude the section with the template 'ads' from the menu... When I tried to `print_r( $template );` There is nothing that will be outputted.

Comment: In addition, I notice that there are only eight entries of $item are printed  on the page. In total I have 14 menu items / pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31989/discussion-between-jhoffmann-and-casper).